# Current jumps up at low resistances - Solar Cell experiment

Tags: energy, experimental-physics, solar-cells

[image]

So I did an experiment with solar cells to obtain an I-V curve where the output current was routed through a variable resistor. near where the short circuit current part should be (at low values of series resistance), the curve jumps up, why?

Comment: You maybe computed the current instead of actually measuring it?

Comment: Did you illuminated that?

Comment: What do you mean? the current was computed by dividing the voltage measured by a voltmeter by the value of the variable resistor